# Randomly generate "-1" or "1" - Shortest Method

Tags: ios, objective-c, random, integer, sign

I need to randomly generate either a "-1" or a "1" to determine the sign of a number randomly... What's the shortest method? I am currently using this but it seems pretty long:

`sign = (round((arc4random() % 2)))-((round((arc4random() % 2))) == 0);`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What about `arc4random_uniform(2) ? -1 : 1`?

or `arc4random_uniform(2)*2 - 1`

Comment: Nice, its like a random binary op

Comment: Oh, very nice! Multiplying by 2 and subtracting 1, didn't even think of that! :)

Comment: **arc4random_uniform() will return a uniformly distributed random number less than upper_bound.** It avoids modulo bias. See the [arc4random manpage](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/arc4random/)

Comment: Another possibility (not really worth another answer): `static const int tmp[] = {-1, 1}; return tmp[arc4random_uniform(2)];`

Comment: @twalberg That's cool too! An array would be very helpful if it was more than just 2 numbers (i.e. -1 an d 1)

Answer (score 1):

```
short int randomNumber () {
return arc4random() % 2 ? 1 : -1;
}
```